# Openpyxl : How to reference cell in row but 1 column over?

Tags: python, openpyxl

I want to create a sum for each of the Total rows in my Excel as shown below for rows 4 and 6.

[image: Final Product]

**EDIT**

Using the below code, I've managed to insert the formulae but I get an error with circular referencing when opening the file and column C is still summing column B for Total complaints.

And Total Attacks column B & C are summing only column C.

I would also still welcome any suggestions for making the SUM dynamic.

```
total = "=SUM(B5:B16)"
total2 = "=SUM(C5:16)"
# Iterate through each line in input file from row 2 (skipping header) to last row
words =  ['Total complaints', 'Total Attacks']
for r_idx, row in enumerate(ws.iter_rows(max_row=ws.max_row, max_col=3)):
        if ws.cell(r_idx+1, 1).value in words:
            for cell in row:
               cell.offset(row = 0, column = 1).value = total.format()
               cell.offset(row = 0, column = 1).value = total2.format()
```

I know this is because of my cell referencing, the code is replacing all my cell values in that row up until the 3rd Column.

How can I alter my code so that column B and column C for total complaints and attacks rows sum upwards?

**EDIT**

I've worked it out using multiple for statements:

```
totalC = "=SUM(B2:B3)"
total2C = "=SUM(C2:C3)"


# Iterate through each line in input file from row 2 (skipping header) to last row
words =  ['Total complaints']
for r_idx, row in enumerate(ws.iter_rows(max_row=ws.max_row, max_col=2)):
        if ws.cell(r_idx+1, 1).value in words:
            for cell in row:
               cell.offset(row = 0, column = 1).value = totalC.format()
words =  ['Total Attacks']
for r_idx, row in enumerate(ws.iter_rows(max_row=ws.max_row, max_col=2)):
        if ws.cell(r_idx+1, 1).value in words:
            for cell in row:
               cell.offset(row = 0, column = 2).value = total2C.format()
```

I think it's a bit long and clunky. I'll be interested if anyone has a neater solution.

Comment: Use `cell.offset()`

Answer (score 0):

You can clean up the code some what to reduce the iterations thru Column A to once only and use the current cell attribute values to create the formulas specific to that cell.
 The code below is an example replacing all of your current example code.

EDIT
The code example now sets the lower range of the sum formula to 2 for row 2 at start. This way the formula so includes all cells from row 2 up to but not including the row 'Total complaints'. It then resets this lower range to the same row the formula in entered so the next formula calculates from there up to but not including the row 'Total Attacks'. This will manage any [number of] rows added into the sheet between rows 2 and 3.

```
...
words = ['Total complaints', 'Total Attacks']
word_index = 0
sum_low_range = 2
for row in ws.iter_rows(max_row=ws.max_row, max_col=2):
    if row[0].value == words[word_index]:
        for cell in row:
            cell_letter = cell.offset(row=0, column=1).column_letter
            calculation_row = cell.row - 1
            cell.offset(row=0, column=1).value = \
                '=SUM({0}{1}:{0}{2})'.format(cell_letter, sum_low_range, calculation_row)
        sum_low_range = cell.row
        word_index += 1
```

Using your example data
cell B4 will have the formula =SUM(B2:B3)
cell C4 will have the formula =SUM(C2:C3)
cell B6 will have the formula =SUM(B4:B5)
cell C6 will have the formula =SUM(C4:C5)

Comment: Thank you! I just wanted to check  is the SUM dynamic? In mine, it will include any rows added into the sheet between rows 2 and 3.

Comment: Your formulas are hard coded, summing just two cell range B2 to B3 and C2 to C3. If you add additional rows between rows 2 and 3 the formulas will still sum just the cells in those two rows. I'm not sure how it can include additional rows. The example code I gave, as it was, handles additional columns reliant on the **max_col=** value in the iterate line being increased if more columns were added. It does not manage additional rows since the SUM calculation is based on 2 cells from the cell holding the formula. Easy enough to update the code to handle additional rows added between rows 2 and 3

Comment: I have updated the code to manage additional rows.

Comment: Hi Moken, thank you for the suggestion! Although it executes, it was including the Total Complaints total in the sum and when I tried to amend it I got an error when opening the excel file saying that excel removed openpyxl parts which didn't work and they turned out to be from this part of the code.

Comment: The 'Total complaints' summing is based on your edit where the formula sums row 2 and 3. The 'Total Attacks' summing is based on your image which shows 'Total Attacks' is the sum of B4 to B5 i.e. 'Total complaints' + 'Attacks'.